# «Но(,) как» — запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, как

В этом предложении нужна ли запятая между **но** и **как**? Мне кажется, что нужна, так как эту часть можно перенести.

*Не пойми неправильно, **но, как** ты собиралась добраться со мной до города, если сама плоха в обращении с магией*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Не пойми неправильно, но как ты собиралась добраться со мной до города, если сама плоха в обращении с магией?***

Запятая здесь нежелательна, хотя формально кажется, что перестановка возможна: *Не пойми неправильно, но,  если (ты) сама плоха в обращении с магией, как ты собиралась добраться со мной до города?*

Дело в том, что его структура должна прочитываться ясно. КАК — это не подчинительный союз, а **вопросительное слово в главном предложении.** И само предложение не самое обычное. Оно называется **несобственно условным  и имеет фразеологический характер.**

**Смысловые отношения** такие: вряд ли возможна первая часть, если верна вторая. Изменять что-либо в его структуре нежелательно, оно должно восприниматься **как единое целое.**

**Примеры** предложений похожей структуры (риторические вопросы): *Как можно осуждать других, если сам виноват? Какой же это кот, если он боится мышей?*

**Примечание.** Также желательно помнить о том, что обособленное предложение имеет вставочную интонацию. Это означает, что оно выделяется паузами и произносится в пониженной тональности.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна запятая.

Если там можно поставить запятую, то эту часть можно изъять и будет нормально звучать. Смотрим результат:
*Не пойми неправильно, но если сама плоха в обращении с магией.*
Совсем не звучит. Нарушена структура предложения.
Плюс есть похожие вопросы на этом сайте, где также сказано, что запятая не нужна.

Запятая после НО ставится, если НО относится ко второй части.
Например:
*Но, как мне сообщили, она сама плоха в обращении с магией.*
А в этом вопросе НО явно относится к следующей части, и ставить запятую — ошибка.

В этом предложении прямой, а не косвенный вопрос, и должен стоять вопросительный знак.